# The meaning of "ring in tax season with us"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "ring in" in "ring in tax season with us"? Is it to accompany the arrival of tax season with bells? But it sounds a bit strange. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Looks like a nonce coinage riffing off ***Ring in the New Year*** - a *figurative* usage that doesn't normally have much to do with actual ***bells***. And since it's exhorting you to do this ***online***, it doesn't seem to be connected to ***ring / call** us on the **phone** to arrange your tax affairs*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit strange.

I assume it is referencing the idea of "ringing in the Christmas season" - yes, with bells. It is treating "Tax Season" as something to be welcomed and celebrated.

I find the lack of an article before "Tax Season" odd as well.

Comment: I don't find the lack of an article odd. Ring in Leaf Fall Season with Acme Blower Hire.

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations!